# Logging emits multiple copies of a message and the number of copies increases each time a new thread is created

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-logging

I have a multithreaded Python application I'm working on (testing on Windows 10 x64, 21H2 with Python 3.11.1) and I'm seeing a repetition of messages in my logs. I thought at first it was having a daemon thread not getting cleaned up but using non-daemon threads and explicitly closing my logging handlers didn't resolve it. I tried `.join()`ing the thread before a new one was spawned with no change.

The messages look like this:

```
Hello
thread1:23460:18652 2023-04-27 11:18:25,569 - threadTest - WARNING: Hello
thread1 is dead, remove from threads = {'thread1': <Thread(thread1, stopped 23460)>}
Hello
thread2:21108:18652 2023-04-27 11:18:30,580 - threadTest - WARNING: Hello
thread2:21108:18652 2023-04-27 11:18:30,580 - threadTest - WARNING: Hello
thread2 is dead, remove from threads = {'thread2': <Thread(thread2, stopped 21108)>}
...(and so on with three entries for thread3 etc)...
```

Code to reproduce the messages is as follows. I see the same behavior if I add a `fileHandler` (i.e. multiple copies of each message in the log file):

```
import time
import threading
import logging
import logging.config

def thread_worker():
    name = "threadTest"
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    log_formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(threadName)s:%(thread)d:%(process)d %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)
    print("Hello")
    logger.warning("Hello")
    time.sleep(2)
    for handler in logger.handlers: # Maybe a duplicate handler? Let's close
        handler.close()
    return

def main():
    threads: dict[str, threading.Thread] = dict()
    i = 1
    while True:
        thread_test = threading.Thread(target = thread_worker, name = f"thread{str(i)}")
        threads[f"thread{str(i)}"] = thread_test
        thread_test.start()
        time.sleep(5)
        dead_threads: list[str] = list()
        for thread_name, thread in threads.items():
            if not thread.is_alive():
                print(f"{thread_name} is dead, remove from {threads = }")
                thread.join()
                dead_threads.append(thread_name)
                
        for thread_name in dead_threads:
            _ = threads.pop(thread_name)
        i += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I hope someone can see what I'm sure is an obvious problem I'm missing!

Comment: You called `addHandler`, but not `removeHandler`.  That's why.  Why create a new handler in each thread, instead of just using a global?

Comment: Absolutely right @Tim, realized that while editing and posting an answer to that effect - good eye!

Answer (score 1):

While I was cleaning up my question slightly I realized what was happening - the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module has a hierarchy of loggers such that errors can propagate out (or not with the `propagate` attribute) from libraries/APIs/etc and so there is a root logger that lives across threads. Any logger can also have any number of a given handler type attached to it. Combine these 2 and my code is dutifully getting the logger named `threadTest` and then adding another handler to it (as @TimRoberts pointed out in a comment while I was writing this answer).

Changing the `for handler in logger.handlers:` section to print out each handler:

```
for handler in logger.handlers:
        print(f"{handler = }, {type(handler)}")
```

and we're greeted with:

```
Hello
thread1:28572:25364 2023-04-27 13:41:06,847 - threadTest - WARNING: Hello
handler = <StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>
thread1 is dead, remove from threads = {'thread1': <Thread(thread1, stopped 28572)>}
Hello
thread2:26680:25364 2023-04-27 13:41:11,863 - threadTest - WARNING: Hello
thread2:26680:25364 2023-04-27 13:41:11,863 - threadTest - WARNING: Hello
handler = <StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>
handler = <StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>
```

‍♂️ The actual application is split across a lot of files and the logging is brought in as a module so I hadn't considered how `logging` was working. The minimal example made it a lot more clear and that's when I looked up the `logging` docs.

Final fix for me was ensuring either handlers are removed when a module running in a thread cleans up or checking if a given handler type was already present (I can get away with this as the architecture is designed with only a single handler per type).

Comment: You resolved it yourself, but I'm just here to provide links: Python docs have howto section for some libs. Logging HOWTO - https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html It explains the hierarchy of logs and propagation of logs to parent logger's handler, as well as how it works with different logging levels on logger, parent, and their handlers :)

Comment: Thank you @h4z3, I was tunnel-vision on my broader code & issues there and hadn't stopped to actually read the fine manual on logging as it had been brought in by one of our internal modules. This was the first time I'd seen this issue as we usually had separate Python instances so the duplicate handlers had been hidden in the internal module until I came along and needed some threads! The logging HOWTO/cookbook/etc is great.